# Flutter- Mapbox Drag marker and get new position

Tags: flutter, dart, mapbox, drag, mapbox-gl

Currently i am using this package `mapbox_gl: ^0.12.0`

How do I call drag end function and get new position?

```
final String _fillPatternImage = “assets/custom-icon.png”;

void _onMapCreated(MapboxMapController controller) {

this.controller = controller;

//controller.dr
//controller.onSymbolTapped.add(_onSymbolTapped);

this.controller.addSymbol(
      SymbolOptions(
        iconSize: 3,
        draggable: true,
        geometry: LatLng(
          _locationData.latitude,
          _locationData.longitude,
        ),
        iconImage: _fillPatternImage,
),);}
```

Comment: Please be a bit more precise. I am not sure what you mean with 'drag end' function

Comment: drag end means marker drop function. check this example https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/drag-a-marker/

Comment: @TechMan have you defined how to detect end of drag event?